# Xcode NSTaggedPointerString not showing unless Print Description

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I just updated to XCode 7.3 and now when trying to inspect a JSON dictionary in the inspector, I'm no longer able to see the key/value if it is NSTaggedPointerString type as a readable string -- rather, it's just codes-- unless I print it in the console.  NSCFString still is readable.

Is there a fix for this? Thanks!